# Compiler flag to force caller to capture return value and make compile error or warning in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-flags

I have a method in class which returns bool. This bool signifies if the call was successful or or not. Many a time users of this method misses to capture the bool

```
bool bar()
{
    return true; //or false in some cases
}


bool result = bar(); //
bar();// Can we get a warning or compiler error here
```

This is similar to [Force function to return value and make compile error C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853025/force-function-to-return-value-and-make-compile-error-c-sharp)
But the answers there are not applicable here.

I am using gcc 4.4.7

Comment: [[nodiscard]] from c++17 is the solution now.

Answer (score 3):

The caller is free to ignore that value and the compiler will happily optimize it out. If you want the caller to be "forcefully" acknowledged of a failure, in a standard way in regard to both C++ and design, throw an exception because unhandled exceptions will call `std::terminate`.
Alternatively, set an internal value that forbids further operation as in `std::ios`.

Answer (score 2):

Statements may be simple expressions (assignment is also a typed expression) - so generally no.

You can implement this as a runtime functionality though:

```
template<typename ResultType>
class CheckReturn {
    public:
        CheckReturn(ResultType value) : m_value(value), m_checked(false) { }
        ~CheckReturn(void) { assert(m_checked); }
        operator ResultType (void) { m_checked = true; return m_value; }

    private:
        ResultType m_value;
        bool m_checked;
};
```

then

```
CheckReturn<bool> foo() { return false; }
...
if(foo()) { } // ok
foo(); // assertion failure at runtime
```

Comment: wow! That is very intelligent.
I am looking for a something so I don't have to change the signature.

Comment: @NewCoder without changing the signature the only other way is black's suggestion: use exceptions for exceptional control flow (i.e. values that must be caught) - you can combine the two approaches (throw an exception in `~CheckReturn`) to avoid the (small) overhead of stack unrolling in *normal* control flow i.e. where you capture the return value.